# How do I prevent Jenkins jobs starting after startup?

Tags: jenkins

After starting a jenkins it begins executing dozens of jobs.

We tried the quiet start plugin but it just delays the issue until you cancel quiet mode: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/quiet-start-plugin

Is there a way to disable the execution of jobs on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself, Why are they in the queue?

[Preventing jobs from running](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203737684-How-can-I-prevent-jenkins-from-starting-new-jobs-after-a-restart-) still leaves them in the queue.

To stop them from running, I prefer a groovy.init call:

```
Jenkins.instance.doQuietDown()
```

You would also then need to [purge the queue](https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/purge-build-queue-by-name.groovy) to eliminate them, at least temporarily.

Or just also execute:

```
Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()
```

But, if you have polling, triggers, or scheduled tasks, new events could continue to queue up. Interrupted pipelines can also resume.

You could also simply take all your nodes offline.